# Validar cuenta con el correo electrónico

Tags: java, oracle

Estoy realizando un `login` el cual al momento de dar de alta un usuario pretendo que se mande un correo electrónico de verificación, soy nuevo en esto y no tengo una idea por donde comenzar, ¿alguien que tenga alguna recomendación, algún ejemplo o algún post que me pueda ayudar? Se los agradecería mucho, estoy utilizando `Java` y `Oracle`.

Comment: Hay un post que te puede ayudar mucho https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/como-enviar-correo-electronico-con-java-a-traves-de-gmail.aspx  es de una libreria en java, no sé si haya otra mejor, pero pues, en su momento me ayudó mucho

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Un modelo que he usado es aunque no inicia precisamente en java sino en java.android es:
PD: en java usa la libreria de javax.mail...

1) Apartir del registro envias un email que en su interior tenga un boton ( de los tipicos click aqui para verificar ) que tengan link a un backend, algun api que tengas, digamos que por comodidad yo a veces lo hago con php porque es muy sencillo,

2) El link podria enviar por medio de POST variables como un token de un unico uso el cual comparas con la bd (como te dije a mi me gusta php, pero puedes desplegar un api desde java tambien) y verificas que quien de click ahi en dicho link es sin duda el user ( pues seria la unica forma de que el tenga el token unico )

este proceso de verificacion de cuentas de correo electronico creo que es mas de forma que de lenguaje, como tal no hay una forma unica de hacerlo pues correos hay muchos posibles, con dominios infinitos. a fin lo que se busca es completar el circuito.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes crear un hash de usuario y mandarlo por correo mediante un link en el contenido.

```
select dbms_random.string('u',40) from dual;
```

Con esto obtienes un hash dinamico, retornaria algo como esto `LHSAGSWYVTSAJFITFUVCPGDKNMZJSMQUIPKRZTVM` lo guardas en un campo y eso lo enviar por mail.

Puedes enviar el correo mediante oracle creado un trigger en tu tabla

```
create trigger USUARIO_TRIG
    before insert
    on USUARIO
    for each row
DECLARE
  V_ASUNTO varchar2(500);
  V_MENSAJE varchar2(500);
BEGIN

    P_ASUNTO    := 'Confirmacion de Cuenta';
    V_MENSAJE := 'Se ha creado el usuario ' || NEW.Code; -- aqui agregas todo lo que precises como tu hash para confirmar la cuenta ejemplo www.tudominio.com/confirmar?id=LHSAGSWYVTSAJFITFUVCPGDKNMZJSMQUIPKRZTVM

    html_email('desde@tudominio.com',
               'hasta@tudominio.com',
               P_MENSAJE,
               V_MSJ_TRASNF,
               V_MSJ_TRASNF);

END;
```

y luego enviarlo con este procedimiento que debes insertar en tu base

```
create procedure html_email(
    p_to            in varchar2,
    p_from          in varchar2,
    p_subject       in varchar2,
    p_text          in varchar2 default null,
    p_html          in varchar2 default null)
    --p_smtp_hostname in varchar2,
    --p_smtp_portnum  in varchar2)
is
    l_boundary      varchar2(255) default 'a1b2c3d4e3f2g1';
    l_connection    utl_smtp.connection;
    l_body_html     clob := empty_clob; 
    l_offset        number;
    l_ammount       number;
    l_temp          varchar2(32767) default null;
    p_smtp_hostname varchar2(500);
    p_smtp_portnum  varchar2(100);
begin


    p_smtp_hostname := 'mail.tudominio.com';

    p_smtp_portnum  := 25;


    l_connection := utl_smtp.open_connection( p_smtp_hostname, p_smtp_portnum );
    utl_smtp.helo( l_connection, p_smtp_hostname );
    utl_smtp.mail( l_connection, p_from );
    utl_smtp.rcpt( l_connection, p_to );

    l_temp := l_temp || 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ||  chr(13) || chr(10);
    l_temp := l_temp || 'To: ' || p_to || chr(13) || chr(10);
    l_temp := l_temp || 'From: ' || p_from || chr(13) || chr(10);
    l_temp := l_temp || 'Subject: ' || p_subject || chr(13) || chr(10);
    l_temp := l_temp || 'Reply-To: ' || p_from ||  chr(13) || chr(10);
    l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=' ||
                         chr(34) || l_boundary ||  chr(34) || chr(13) ||
                         chr(10);

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the headers
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( l_body_html, false, 10 );
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(l_temp),1,l_temp);


    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the text boundary
    l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
    l_temp   := '--' || l_boundary || chr(13)||chr(10);
    l_temp   := l_temp || 'content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii' ||
                  chr(13) || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(10);
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(l_temp),l_offset,l_temp);

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the plain text portion of the email
    l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(p_text),l_offset,p_text);

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the HTML boundary
    l_temp   := chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10)||'--' || l_boundary ||
                    chr(13) || chr(10);
    l_temp   := l_temp || 'content-type: text/html;' ||
                   chr(13) || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(10);
    l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(l_temp),l_offset,l_temp);

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the HTML portion of the message
    l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(p_html),l_offset,p_html);

    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Write the final html boundary
    l_temp   := chr(13) || chr(10) || '--' ||  l_boundary || '--' || chr(13);
    l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
    dbms_lob.write(l_body_html,length(l_temp),l_offset,l_temp);


    ----------------------------------------------------
    -- Send the email in 1900 byte chunks to UTL_SMTP
    l_offset  := 1;
    l_ammount := 1900;
    utl_smtp.open_data(l_connection);
    while l_offset < dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) loop
        utl_smtp.write_data(l_connection,
                            dbms_lob.substr(l_body_html,l_ammount,l_offset));
        l_offset  := l_offset + l_ammount ;
        l_ammount := least(1900,dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) - l_ammount);
    end loop;
    utl_smtp.close_data(l_connection);
    utl_smtp.quit( l_connection );
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_body_html);

end;
```

Este procedimiento de envio de mail lo puedes retocar para pasarle tu host y puesto como parametro, todo ya depende de ti.